# Calling custom method from core interface

Tags: java, spring, interface, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I am extending a `DbNodeServiceImpl` class and try to Override a method named
`public void setProperty(NodeRef nodeRef, QName qname, Serializable value)`.

When I am trying to call the method with the help of nodeService interface its calling the default method that is present in DbNodeServiceImpl, not the custom one that i created. How can I implement the same thing? I just want to call my own method with the help of nodeservice Interface.

Comment: How are you creating the instance used to call the method? It should be using an instance like this `NodeService s = new WhateverClassThatExtendsDbNodeServiceImpl()`

Comment: no i am not instantiating i am just injecting the nodeservice  and call that method with the help of that injection. i am just using the refrence of nodeservice s and calling like s.setproperty(x,y,z)

Comment: Show the injection then

Comment: private NodeService nodeService;                                                                                                   public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
  this.nodeService = nodeService;
 }

Comment: Where do you use this injection code?

Comment: in any class where is necessary

Comment: can any one tell where nodeservice bean or nodeserviceimpl bean is defined in alfresco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your own class like this:

```
   <bean id="newOwnService" class="MyNewServiceImpl" init-method="init" parent="org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl" >
         .... some needed properties....

       </bean>
```

Then where you call your method:

```
<bean id="newClass" class="NewClass">
        <property name="somethingName" ref="newOwnService"/>
       </bean>
```

In code:

```
private NodeService somethingName;

public setSomethingName(NodeService somethingName){
    this.somethingName = somethingName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface calls overridden method with same signature. You cannot override a method two times in same implementor class.You should post some code for better explanations

Comment: actually i have a class that extend the DbNodeServiceImpl.class and DbNodeServiceImpl class implement nodeservice interface. i want override a method that defined in nodeservice and implemented in DbNodeServiceImpl but when i am calling that method its calling method that is present in DbNodeServiceImpl class not mine.

Comment: without seeing the code i think you are calling the method on a reference of type DbNodeServiceImpl , not on the other class that extends DbNodeServiceImpl. Show me the specific call instruction

Comment: public class CustomGetProperties extends DbNodeServiceImpl
{  public void setProperty(NodeRef nodeRef, QName qname, Serializable value) throws InvalidNodeRefException
    {
if(dictionaryService.getType(qname).equals(DataTypeDefinition.ENCRYPTED)){ApplicationContext ctx =ApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext();
MetadataEncryptor metadataEncryptor = (MetadataEncryptor)ctx.getBean("metadataEncryptor");              
 Serializable encryptedValue=metadataEncryptor.encrypt(qname,value);
 super.setProperty(nodeRef,qname,encryptedValue);
 }
  else
   super.setProperty(nodeRef, qname, value);

Comment: i am not taking refrence here i am just extending

Comment: super.setProperty.... is a direct call to parent class, in this example DbNodeServiceImpl . Your method always returns a call to DbNodeServiceImpl setProperty method

Comment: yes i want to call that parent class method but before that i want to set encrypted value according to my requirment that thing i impplemented in my method

Comment: @SachinSingh read my comment on the question and show how you are calling instanciating the nodeService.